# Making requests from Flash for URLs with + signs in them

Tags: actionscript-3, amazon-s3, url-encoding

I am hosting images on Amazon S3 and using them in my Flash application. My application receives signed S3 urls that point to the images in S3. The URL looks something like this (line breaks added for clarity):

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/my-image.jpg?
  AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI7PSLIMJFIA2JRQG&
  Expires=1313812683&
  Signature=yhnSe47GRjReUQlfG/S/A+JJTdo=
```

The problem here is with the `+` sign that can occur in the Signature. If I send the `+` sign as-is, then the browser thinks that it's a space, as it should according to the URL specs. Really, S3 shouldn't use `+` signs for this reason, but it seems to be [something they overlooked](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=55746).

Normally this isn't a problem since you just replace the `+` sign with a `%2B`. However, Flash has some default behavior that makes this difficult.

From what I can see, the `URLRequest` object is setup to *always* encode URLs as if it was passed through the `encodeURI` function. I don't see any way to turn this off. Unfortunately, `encodeURI` doesn't encode `+` signs, but it *does* encode `%` signs.

This means that if I leave the `+` sign in there then Flash leaves it alone and S3 thinks I have a space in my URL. If I use `%2B` then Flash turns it into `%252B`, due to encoding the `%`. Doh!

Does anybody see a way around this that I'm missing?

Comment: I tried this by doing a request in `navigateToURL` and `URLLoader` and both showed the url just as you needed. Do you have more to your example for us to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is automatically changes the url submitted to it. Adobe's documentation even tells you to take care and escape unusual characters.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6

Comment: I think you're right. I discovered that the problematic code is actually setting an `Image` component's `source` attribute, rather than using a `URLRequest`. I'm going to see if there is a workaround by using `URLRequest` then feeding the bytes to `Image`.

Comment: Fixed! It turned out to be only the `Image` component that forces the url encoding. Using `Loader` and feeding the resulting bitmap to `Image` works fine. Thanks for the insight.